# What is the fastest way to check multiple trends in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a large dataframe with 25-30 columns, and thousands of lines. 
I need to analyse the trend of some columns and the trend of some column ratios against each other.

Now I have 3 choices:

1) iterate row by row with a simple for i in range(len(df)), and build a series of if/else conditions, comparing each value with the previous and following ones, for different columns;

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df.iloc[i]['col1'] < df.iloc[i]['col2']):
      print ('error type 1')
    if (df.iloc[i]['col2'] < df.iloc[i]['col3']):
      print ('error type 2')
    if (df.iloc[i+1]['col1'] > 2 * df.iloc[i]['col1']):
      print ('error trend 1')
    if (df.iloc[i+1]['col2'] > 2 * df.iloc[i+1]['col2']):
      print ('error trend 2')
    if (df.iloc[i-1]['col2'] > 2 * df.iloc[i]['col2']):
      print ('error trend 2')
   # and so on, with around 40-50 if statements per line
```

2) Iterate with iterrows or itertuples, but I am not sure to be able to access previous and next rows easily

3) create shifted columns and use vectorized operations, but it means I will create around 100 more columns in the dataframe (shift +1, +2,-1, -2 x 20 columns):

```
df['ratio12'] = df['col1'] / df['col2']
df['ratio12up1'] = df['ratio12'].shift(-1)
df['ratio12up2'] = df['ratio12'].shift(-2)
df['ratio12dn1'] = df['ratio12'].shift(1)
df['ratio12dn2'] = df['ratio12'].shift(2)
df['ratio23'] = df['col2'] / df['col3']
df['ratio23up1'] = df['ratio23'].shift(-1)
df['ratio23up2'] = df['ratio23'].shift(-2)
df['ratio23dn1'] = df['ratio23'].shift(1)
df['ratio23dn2'] = df['ratio23'].shift(2)
df['ratio34'] = df['col3'] / df['col4']
#..... for other 10 ratios
# and then do the checks on all these new columns, like:
peak_ratio12 = ( (df['ratio12'] / df['ratio12up1']) > 1.5 && (df['ratio12'] / df['ratio12dn1'] > 1.5) )
```

EDIT: EXAMPLE: I have this table:

```
   Index col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
   0     732    58   18  10    6    3    3
   1     754    60   18  10    6    3    3
   2     3964   365  98  34   34    17  13
   3     4286   417 110  36   35    19  15
   4     5807   545 155  54   53    27  21
   5     1681   132  46  16   13    9   8
   6     542    620  13  11    4    3   2
   7     319    38   30  20    4    2   2
   8     286    22   17  10    3    2   2
   9     324    25   18  10    3    2   2
   10    370    29   10   0    4    2   2
   11    299    28   19  10    3    2   2
   12    350    36   14  11    6    3   4
   13    309    34   14  11    7    3   4
```

On this infinitely small part of data I would like to find errors:

- when a value in the columns becomes 2x or half the previous and next values (so in line 2, 5, 6 for example)
- when a successive column is higher than the previous (like col2 >col1 in line 6, col7>col6 in line 12 and 13, etc.
- and a huge number of other checks on these columns (like col1/col2 must be pretty constant, col2/col3 the same, col6+col7 must be smaller than col3, etc)

My main problem is on checking column ratios with previous and next values. All other checks are easily vectorized.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: can u add sample data

Comment: You can directly do `df['ratio12'] / df['ratio12'].shift()` without the need to have an extra column